# Why is a map lookup faster then an array lookup in firefox while slower in chrome?

Tags: arrays, google-chrome, firefox, hashtable, lookup

As per this benchmarking test: http://jsperf.com/array-vs-hashtable-lookup

Why is an array lookup faster then a map lookup in chrome while the opposite is true in firefox?

Comment: That is as *terrible* microbenchmark and should not used as any performance indicator. The browser engines can do *all sorts of unexpected optimizations*; they do all the time, but in that test they are given much more leeway with what they can do (the entire object creation can be elided and still have an equivalent program!). Plus you are also timing the creation of the objects. Firefox is *very* aggressive in such cases and "rewriting" the operations. Chrome has a very good subsystem but, from my experience, is less aggressive in up-front transformation optimizations.

Comment: P.S. An object is a [Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) and *not* a hash-table. There is *no requirement* that a hash-table is used in the implementation so to call it such is misleading. Implementations can and do change the actual backing used (based on number of keys, hidden classes, etc.). Browsers attempt to keep object[key] access "fast" (as an optimization based on expected usage) but there is *no* requirements on implementation or performance bounds that result from such.